# compile lib's functions with another lib in C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

i want to compile a lib with another. For my exemple i have a lib1 with one function func1 and i have a lib2 with one function func2 who use func1 of my lib1.
So i just ar rc my lib1

And i want to compile my lib2's function with my lib1, here is the makefile of my lib2 without clean rules

```
SRC =   func2.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

NAME    =   lib2.a

all: $(NAME)

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    gcc -c -o $@ $< -L./../ -l:lib1.a
$(NAME):    $(OBJ)
    ar rsc $(NAME) $(OBJ) ../lib1.a
    cp $(NAME) -t ../
```

In my code, it's just :

```
#include "lib/lib1/lib1.h"
#include "lib/lib2/lib2.h"
int main(void)
{
    func2();
    return (0);
}
```

and i compile like that :
gcc -o exe -L./lib/ -l:lib1.a -L./lib/ -l:lib2.a main.c -Wall -Wextra

so i have the error :
in function `func2': func2.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to` func1'

I want to say that if i add func1(); in my main it work:

```
#include "lib/lib1/lib1.h"
#include "lib/lib2/lib2.h"
int main(void)
{
    func1();
    func2();
    return (0);
}
```

I want to know why my first main code doesn't compile please ?
Have a nice day

Comment: The order of command-line options is in general significant.  The order of options specifying source files, object files, and link libraries on the compiler command line is especially significant.  Generally speaking, unresolved names in one object or library are resolved only against objetcs and libraries appearing later on the command line.  So move the `-l` options to the end.

Comment: Thanks, but when i do that, i compile like that in my Makefile :
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o exe  main.c  -L./lib/ -l:lib1.a -L./lib/ -l:lib2.a 
And it's still doesn't work

Comment: The order of libs matter too. Put -l:lib1.a after -l:lib2.a

Comment: All right, this worked, thanks Andreas. But i wonder:
what does it change if I link lib1 before lib2 knowing that lib2 was compiled before with lib1 ?

Comment: @willh, the order in which the libraries were compiled does not directly matter.  The required link order is a function of objects' *dependencies* on one another, in the specific manner I described in my first comment.